# IO::Socket::SSL: SSL connect attempt failed

Tags: perl, ssl, mojolicious, sslhandshakeexception

I do request to `https://bank.gov.ua`

```
my $ua       =  Mojo::UserAgent->new;
$ua->get("https://bank.gov.ua/NBUStatService/v1/statdirectory/exchange?valcode=EUR&date=$date_now&json");
```

And get error:

```
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:3010: new ctx 146452496
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:1638: don't start handshake: IO::Socket::SSL=GLOB(0xc955978)
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:787: ssl handshake not started
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:829: using SNI with hostname bank.gov.ua
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:864: request OCSP stapling
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:894: call Net::SSLeay::connect
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:897: done Net::SSLeay::connect -> -1
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:907: ssl handshake in progress
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:894: call Net::SSLeay::connect
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:897: done Net::SSLeay::connect -> -1
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:900: local error: SSL connect attempt failed
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:903: fatal SSL error: SSL connect attempt failed
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:3059: free ctx 146452496 open=
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:3063: free ctx 146452496 callback
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:3070: OK free ctx 146452496
```

I can do request with `curl` from this host to give url with no problem.

Does any know what problem is when I do this via IO::Socket::SSL (Mojo::UserAgent)?

Comment: Did not work initially for me since server seemed to croak on TLS 1.3 requests. Works for me now, maybe the server got fixed?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich: What you mean: croak on TLS 1.3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This server is pretty strange:

- the first request with `openssl s_client -connect bank.gov.ua:443` fails with the server simply closing the connection: *"SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 303 bytes"*
- the Mojo::UserAgent code fails too
- doing a request with an explicit TLS 1.2 succeeds: `openssl s_client -connect bank.gov.ua:443 -tls1_2`
- trying the first request again suddenly succeeds too
- an the Mojo::UserAgent code now succeeds too

My only explanation is some firewall or load balancer which temporarily white lists an IP address in case it has seen a valid TLS ClientHello - and which considers TLS 1.3 not a valid one.